# Tomcat not retrieving files with accents after restart

Tags: centos, tomcat, localization, language

A few days ago I had a problem with an application running on Tomcat, it wasn't able to find files in the filesystem containing accents in the name (like, for example, "reportsandonà.pdf"). I discovered that it was a "locale" problem and i solved this by changing the locale from en_GB.UTF-8 to it_IT.UTF-8

Now i'm facing another problem. Whenever i restart Tomcat with this command: "service tomcat restart" the problem is again there, and i have to restart the whole machine in order to fix it.

I'm using tomcat 7 on Centos 6 64 bit, and this is the start/stop/restart script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat

case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8` to your start/stop script.